# Steroids+Angular1.3.15 iOS (AppGyver)

Tags: android, ios, angularjs, steroids, appgyver

I'm trying to implement font scaling in Steroids+Angular1.3.15 (AppGyver) hybrid app. I decided to use `$localStorage` to store current font size. It all works great on android devices but not on iOS.. Actually in iOS it works for the newly opened `WebViews` but not the ones that are already displayed.

Links for font scaling:

```
<a class="font-size font-small" data-remote="true" ng-class="{current: fontSize == 'rem-base-small'}" ng-click="setFontSize('rem-base-small')">A</a>
<a class="font-size font-medium" data-remote="true" ng-class="{current: fontSize == 'rem-base-medium'}" ng-click="setFontSize('rem-base-medium')">A</a>
<a class="font-size font-large" data-remote="true" ng-class="{current: fontSize == 'rem-base-large'}" ng-click="setFontSize('rem-base-large')">A</a>
```

and in my controller:

```
$scope.fontSize = $localStorage.fontSize || 'rem-base-medium'

$scope.setFontSize = function(size) {
  $localStorage.fontSize = size
  $scope.fontSize = size
}
```

I use `myfontsize` directive on `<html>` tag to update UI. My directive looks like so:

```
var sharedStuff = angular.module('sharedStuff', ['ngStorage'])

  sharedStuff.directive('myfontsize', function($localStorage) {
    function link(scope, element, attrs) {
        var format,
            timeoutId;

        function updateClass() {
          element.removeClass('rem-base-large')
          element.removeClass('rem-base-medium')
          element.removeClass('rem-base-small')

          $localStorage.fontSize = $localStorage.fontSize || "rem-base-medium"
          element.addClass($localStorage.fontSize)
        }

        scope.$watch(attrs.myCurrentTime, function(value) {
          format = value;
          updateClass();
        });

        element.on('$destroy', function() {
          clearInterval(timeoutId);
        });

        // start the UI update process; save the timeoutId for canceling
        timeoutId = setInterval(function() {
          updateClass(); // update DOM
        }, 1000);
      }

      return {
        link: link
      };
  })
```

If somebody could shed some light on why it works on android but it doesn't on iOS, I would be much obliged. Alternatively if you have better solution to achieve my goal and don't mind sharing, please do :)

Comment: When you say "it works for the newly opened `WebViews` but not the ones that are already displayed" do you mean those that are already displayed are preloaded and it doesn't work on those? You can try asking your question [here](http://community.appgyver.com/) as well.

Comment: Each time link is clicked in the side menu
`
  $scope.switchPage = function(item) {
    webView = new steroids.views.WebView(item.url);
    steroids.layers.push(webView);
    steroids.drawers.hide()
  };
`
fonts are scaled correctly, so yes, it doesn't work on preloaded views with iOS